# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

With iOS 10+ its necessary to Add the NSCameraUsageDescription
Allow Photos For Encryption Privacy Camera Usage requirement.  This causes a Pop Up to appear when I launch the following code the first time:

The Pop up is Causing the following Error it seems:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex (NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex < 2) {

        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;

        imagePickerController.delegate = self;

        if (buttonIndex == 0) {          
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        } else if ( buttonIndex == 1) {
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        }

        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];

    }
}
```

As soon as I select OK on the Pop up to allow the app to use the camera it crashes.

If I go back into the app, and try it again, because the Pop Up doesn't appear, my code will execute, and I can get the image accordingly.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{


    NSString *tmpFilePath = @"";
    tmpFilePath = [_myHelper retrieveAppDirectory:self.username];


    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];


    if (!image) {

        [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }


    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%d.securedData", self.photos.count + 1];


    [_myHelper performEncryptionForSecuredData:image filePath:tmpFilePath fileName:imageName];


    [self.photos addObject:image];

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I know this has been asked so many times, before.  Any idea On what I am possibly doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Sorry for such a long question.  I have tried  the following but none seem to work:

[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil]

I also tried setting up a [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
}

But it always seems to be that darn popup showing up for the first time.  After you tell iOS it can use the camera, the error won't appear anymore.....

Comment: The obvious way to avoid this problem is to get your app through the whole camera / photo library permission dance _before_ displaying the image picker controller.

Comment: Matt I'm not 100% sure on your comments.  The Pop Up which asks you to Allow The app access to the camera occurs the first time you try to use Camera doesn't it?  Is there another way I can allow the use of the camera without the Dialog Prompt?

Answer (score 0):

As `UIActionSheet` is deprecated from iOS 8.3 you must use `UIAlertController` for all **Alert / ActionSheet**.

Please Use below code for `ActionSheet`:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:nil      //  Must be "nil", otherwise a blank title area will appear above our two buttons
                                message:nil
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* button0 = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
                                  //  UIAlertController will automatically dismiss the view
                              }];

UIAlertAction* button1 = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"Camera"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
                                  //  The user tapped on "Camera"
                                  UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

                                  imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
                                  imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                                  imagePickerController.delegate = self;
                                  [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
                              }];

UIAlertAction* button2 = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"Photo Library"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
                                  //  The user tapped on "Camera"
                                  UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

                                  imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
                                  imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                                  imagePickerController.delegate = self;
                                  [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
                              }];
    [alert addAction:button0];
    [alert addAction:button1];
    [alert addAction:button2];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Use your same Imagepicker delegate.

Hope this will helps.